# How to solve this grammar recursion?

Tags: recursion, grammar

I found this grammar for a calculator:

```
<Expression> ::= <ExpressionGroup> | <BinaryExpression> | <UnaryExpression> | <LiteralExpression>
<ExpressionGroup> ::= '(' <Expression> ')'
<BinaryExpression> ::= <Expression> <BinaryOperator> <Expression>
<UnaryExpression> ::= <UnaryOperator> <Expression>
<LiteralExpression> ::= <RealLiteral> | <IntegerLiteral>
<BinaryOperator> ::= '+' | '-' | '/' | '*'
<UnaryOperator> ::= '+' | '-'
<RealLiteral> ::= <IntegerLiteral> '.' | <IntegerLiteral> '.' <IntegerLiteral>
<IntegerLiteral> ::= <Digit> <IntegerLiteral> | <Digit>
<Digit> ::= '0' | '1' |'2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
```

Source: [here](http://www.modelcc.org/examples/simple-arithmetic-expression-language)

It looks great. So I wrote the lexer and started the parser. Now there is an infinite recursion that I can't solve between Expression and BinaryExpression.
My code for expression:

```
boolean isExpression() {
        if (isExpressionGroup() || isBinaryExpression() || isUnaryExpression() || isLiteralExpression()) {
            println("Expression!");
            return true;
        }
        println("Not expression.");
        return false;
}
```

And for binary expression:

```
boolean isBinaryExpression() {
    if (isExpression()) {
        peek(1);
        if (currentLex.token == Token.BINARY_OPERATOR) {
            peek(2);
            if (isExpression()) {
                peek(3);
                println("Binary expression!");
                return true;
            } else peek(0);
        } else peek(0);
    } else peek(0);
    return false;
}
```

So peek(int) is just a function for looking forward without consuming any lexemes. So my problem: My input is '2*3' . isExpression() gets called. isExpressionGroup() fails, because there is no '('. Then the isBinaryExpression() gets called, which calls isExpression(). isExpressionGroup() fails again, and isBinaryExpression() gets called again. And so on, until a stack overflow.

I know, there is ANTLR and JavaCC (and other tools), but I would like to do it without them.

Could anyone give a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with left recursion in a hand-crafted top-descent parser is not easy. Parser generators that solve the problem have years of work in them. There are theoretical reasons for that.

The best solution if you don't want to use a tool is to eliminate the left recursion. The problem if you do it "by the book" is that you'll get an ugly grammar and an ugly parser that will be difficult to use.

But there's another solution. You can add enough rules to represent the precedence hierarchy of the operators, which is something you'd have to do anyway, unless you want to risk a `a+b*c` be parsed as `(a+b)*c`.

There are plenty of examples of non left-recursive grammars for expressions on the Web, and here in SO in particular. I suggest you take one of them, and start from there.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'll modify the grammar.